# Segfault when trying to access a hash in a particular function

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, hashtable

So, I'm trying to make a simple hash data structure for an assignment. As it is, everything works except when i try to access my remove function when i try to compare a key in my hash with a string passed by reference into the function. it segfault on the compare and i've tried to rewrite it but i keep getting the same segfault or a compile error. i'm just not sure what i don't have access to when trying to compare. i can only assume its the ->GetKey but i have access to that in my print function right below it.

```
#ifndef MYSTRINGMAP_H
#define MYSTRINGMAP_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "abstractstringmap.h"
using namespace std;

const int BASE_SIZE = 10;

template <typename T>
class HashEntry
{
  private:
    string m_key;
    T m_value;
  public:
    HashEntry( string k , T v ) : m_key( k ), m_value( v ) {}
    string& getKey() { return m_key; }
    T& getValue() { return m_value; }
};

template <typename T>
class MyStringMap
{
  private:
    HashEntry<T> **m_table;
    int m_size;
    int hash( const string &s ) const;
  public:
    MyStringMap()
    {
      m_table = new HashEntry<T>*[BASE_SIZE];
      m_size = BASE_SIZE;
      for( int i = 0 ; i < m_size ; ++i )
      {
        m_table[i] = NULL;
      }
    }
    int size() const;
    bool isEmpty() const { return ( size() == 0 ); }
    const T& valueOf( const string& key ) const;
    void clear();
    void insert( const string& key , const T& val );
    void remove( const string& k );
    void print() const;
};

template <typename T>
int MyStringMap<T>::hash( const string &s ) const
{
  int hashval = 0;
  for( unsigned int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; ++i )
  {
    char c = s.at(i);
    hashval += int(c);
  }

  return hashval;
}

template <typename T>
int MyStringMap<T>::size() const
{
  int s = 0;
  for( int i = 0 ; i < m_size ; ++i )
  {
    if( m_table[i] != NULL )
    {
      ++s;
    }
  }

  return s;
}

template <typename T>
const T& MyStringMap<T>::valueOf( const string& key ) const
{
  int hashval = hash( key );
  hashval = hashval % m_size;
  while( m_table[hashval] != NULL && hash( m_table[hashval]->getKey() ) != hash( key ) )
  {
    hashval = ( hashval + 1 ) % m_size;
  }

  if( m_table[hashval] == NULL )
  {
    string err = "ERROR [valueOf] Key not found.";
    throw err;
  }
  else
  {
    return m_table[hashval]->getValue();
  }
}

template <typename T>
void MyStringMap<T>::clear()
{
  for( int i = 0 ; i < m_size ; ++i )
  {
    if( m_table[i] != NULL )
    {
      delete m_table[i];
    }
  }
  delete m_table;
  m_table = new HashEntry<T>*[BASE_SIZE];
  m_size = BASE_SIZE;
  for( int i = 0 ; i < m_size ; ++i )
  {
    m_table[i] = NULL;
  }

  return;
}

template <typename T>
void MyStringMap<T>::insert( const string& key , const T& val )
{
  if( size() >= m_size )
  {
    int tempsize = m_size * 2;
    HashEntry<T>** temp;
    temp = new HashEntry<T>*[( m_size * 2 )];
    for( int i = 0 ; i < m_size ; ++i )
    {
      temp[i] = m_table[i];
    }
    clear();
    m_table = temp;
    m_size = tempsize;
  }

  int hashval = hash( key );
  hashval = hashval % m_size;
  while( m_table[hashval] != NULL && hash( m_table[hashval]->getKey() ) != hash( key ) )
  {
    hashval = ( hashval + 1 ) % m_size;
  }
  if( m_table[hashval] != NULL )
  {
    delete m_table[hashval];
  }
  m_table[hashval] = new HashEntry<T>( key, val );

  return;
}

template <typename T>
void MyStringMap<T>::remove( const string& k )
{
  int removeIndex = -1;
  for( int i = 0 ; i < m_size ; ++i )
  {
    if( hash( m_table[i]->getKey() ) == hash( k ))
    {
      removeIndex = i;
    }
  }

if( removeIndex >= 0 )
{
  delete m_table[removeIndex];
  m_table[removeIndex] = NULL;
}


  return;
}

template <typename T>
void MyStringMap<T>::print() const
{
  for( int i = 0 ; i < m_size ; ++i )
  {
    if( m_table[i] != NULL )
    {
      cout << endl << "< " << m_table[i]->getKey() << ", " << m_table[i]->getValue() << " > ";
    }
  }
  cout << endl;

  return;
}

#endif
```

as for the tester we were given:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "mystringmap.h"
using namespace std;

// --------------------------------------------------------------
void test0()
{
  MyStringMap<char> grades;

  cout << endl;  
  cout << "--- Test 0 ----" << endl;
  cout << "Is Empty? " << boolalpha << grades.isEmpty() << endl; 
  cout << "Size = " << grades.size()  << endl;


  grades.insert("Nate",'A');
  grades.insert("George",'C');
  grades.insert("Karl",'F');
  grades.insert("John",'B');
  grades.insert("Will",'B');  

  cout << endl;
  cout << "Is Empty? " << boolalpha << grades.isEmpty() << endl; 
  cout << "Size = " << grades.size()  << endl;

  grades.print();


  return;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
void test1()
{
  MyStringMap<string> thelist;

  cout << endl;
  cout << "--- Test 1 ----" << endl;
  cout << "Is Empty? " << boolalpha << thelist.isEmpty() << endl; 
  cout << "Size = " << thelist.size()  << endl;


  thelist.insert("Fry","Naughty");
  thelist.insert("Leela","Naughty");
  thelist.insert("Hermes","Naughty");
  thelist.insert("Qubert","Naughty");
  thelist.insert("Zoidberg","Nice");  
  thelist.insert("Scruffy","Naughty");
  thelist.insert("Bender","Naughty");
  thelist.insert("Zapp","Naughty");
  thelist.insert("Kiff","Naughty");

  thelist.insert("Leela","Nice");  

  cout << endl;
  cout << "Is Empty? " << boolalpha << thelist.isEmpty() << endl; 
  cout << "Size = " << thelist.size()  << endl;

  thelist.print();

  cout << endl;
  cout << "Testing remove" << endl;
  cout << "Removing non-Humans" << endl;  

  thelist.remove("Leela");
  thelist.remove("Zoidberg");
  thelist.remove("Bender");  
  thelist.remove("Kiff");    

  thelist.remove("Nixon");    

  thelist.print();


  cout << endl;
  cout << "Testing Lookup" << endl;

  try 
  {
    cout << "Fry? " << thelist.valueOf("Fry") << endl;  
    cout << "Hermes? " << thelist.valueOf("Hermes") << endl;  
    cout << "Qubert? " << thelist.valueOf("Qubert") << endl;  

    cout << "Nixon? ";
    cout << thelist.valueOf("Nixon") << endl;  
  }
  catch (string s)
  {
    cout << "ERROR : " << s << endl;
  }

  cout << endl;
  //cout << "End of test #1" << endl;
  return;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// --------------------------------------------------------------
// --------------------------------------------------------------
int main ()
{
  cout << "MAP TESTER!!" << endl;

  test0();
  test1();


  //cout << "Q?";
  //cin.ignore();
  //cin.get();

  return 0;
}
```

the .h for this is:

```
#ifndef ABSTRACTSTRINGMAP_H
#define ABSTRACTSTRINGMAP_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


template < typename T >
class AbstractStringMap
{

public:

   /*** ---- Accessor Operations ---- */

// Purpose: Accessor function for the number of elements in the Map
// Returns: number of elements in the Map 
  virtual int size() const = 0;


// Purpose: Checks if a Map is empty
// Returns: 'true' if the Map is empty
//     'false' otherwise  
  virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;


// Purpose: Returns the value associated with a key.
// Parameters: key of the value to be found 
// Returns: 
//     If The Map contains Key then return the value associated with Key.
//     If The Map does not contains Key then THROW SOMETHING!!!
  virtual const T& valueOf(const string& key) const = 0;



  /*** ---- Mutator Operations ---- */

// Purpose: Clears the Map
// Postconditions: an empty Map
  virtual void clear() = 0;


// Purpose: Inserts an element into a Map
// Parameters: Key and  Value to be added to the Map
// Postconditions: The Map now contains the pair < Key, Value >
//     if the Map already contains a value associated with Key,
//     replace it with the parameter Val
  virtual void insert(const string& key, const T& val) = 0;


// Purpose: Removes an element from the Map
// Parameters: K, the Key to remove
// Postconditions: the map does not contains a pair with k as Key
  virtual void remove(const string& k) = 0;


  /*** ---- Output Operations ---- */

// Purpose: Prints the Map with pretty formatting
// No partucular order is required.
  virtual void print() const = 0;


  /*** ---- Utility Functions Operations ---- */

// Purpose: Hashes a string into an integer.
// you shall use this function for your hash-table.
private:
  virtual int hash(const string &s) const = 0;                  

};


#endif
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your code? This line is missing a `)`:  `if( hash( m_table[i]->getKey() ) == hash( k )`

Comment: Pretty sure you can reduce this to a far simpler example. Perhaps 20 lines of code.

Comment: sorry, i did some messing around with it before posting and must have forgot to add the ) to the end of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is that when you resize your table in `insert` you copy the pointers from the old table to the new table but after that you call `clear` which deletes the same pointers.

The resize code in `insert` has another bug because it doesn't rehash the entries, instead it just copies them to the same slots as before even though the table size has changed. This means after resizing the table many of the entries will occupy the wrong slots.

Another bug is that in `remove`

```
if( hash( m_table[i]->getKey() ) == hash( k ))
```

should be

```
if(m_table[i] != NULL && hash( m_table[i]->getKey() ) == hash( k ))
```

But this still leaves the 'not comparing keys bug' (see comments), so really it should be

```
if(m_table[i] != NULL && m_table[i]->getKey() == k)
```

But yet another bug is that this version of remove makes no use of hashing, it just does a linear search through the entire table.

I think there's a bit of work to do on this code.

Comment: the size only changes when all spots are filled. then it doubles in size to allow for other hashes to be filled. commenting out the clear() function on the insert doesnt remove the segfault though. im nearly positive its the same segfault it was before as it happens on the same line. not calling clear just forces the table size to increase because your inserting everything over and over each time its called.

Comment: the only reason i bring this up is because for tester file there arent 10 items being hashed to force my hash to resize. i will probably fix it later but for now i want it to actually function.

Comment: OK, you have other bugs. Another bug is when you insert and delete you compare the hash values of the keys, not the keys themselves. So you could end up overwriting or deleting the wrong key (if two keys happened to have the same hash value). However that's doesn't seem to be the bug that's causing the seg fault. Must be something else but I'm not seeing it right now.

Comment: Same issue in valueof, you do need to compare actual keys, not hash values of keys.

Comment: ok from what ive tried its the "i" in my for loop messing it up, if i just randomly assign a number that's inside my hash array it works fine, just for some reason changing its value makes it segfault.

Comment: actually right after you posted i tried randomly inserting numbers to see what actually segfaulted and learned that i wasn't checking for a NULL when comparing. this fixed the segfault and it runs fine now(outside of the bugs you pointed out)